# First Negative Value Row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I pick the first negative value row using CASE Statement? I do not want to use Where condition since it applies the condition to the entire data.
In the below sample, I just want to make the maximum of negative values (-469) to ABS(-469) which is 469 and leave the rest as is.

My `MAX(CASE WHEN -469)...`does not seem to work. Assume there is an ordering field.

```
Sample 
------
1281
-469
-469
-509
-1359
-1359
-2759
-2829
```

Comment: If I want to make this question simpler, how do I pick a max negative value from this column using CASE statement? Not sure if it still doesn't make sense. I am fairly new to Oracle and I am facing this challenge in my business.

Comment: Do you want to transform both `-469` values, or just one of them?

Comment: Both of them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is no different from `WHERE`, it's checked against every row in your data (unless there is an index on this column). So the best I can think of is

```
UPDATE t
SET Sample = ABS(Sample)
WHERE Sample = (SELECT MAX(Sample) FROM t WHERE Sample < 0)
```

EDIT: just read that you actually need a "maximum of negatives", if you know what is that value, you can manually use `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Sample = -469 THEN ABS(Sample) ELSE Sample END AS Sample
FROM t
```

To do the same automatically (i.e. to find the maximum of negatives and change it):

```
WITH MaxNeg AS (SELECT MAX(Sample) as v FROM t WHERE Sample < 0)
SELECT CASE WHEN Sample = MaxNeg.v THEN ABS(Sample) ELSE Sample END AS Sample
FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change values in your row. You can use the following query.

```
update 
    t
set
    sample = abs(sample) 
where 
     sample = (select max(t.sample) from t where t.sample < 0)
```

But it you only need retrieve absolute value for maximum over negatives then use the following query. Really I think that clause `where` hasn't scary things and you can use it.

```
select abs(max(t.sample)) from t where t.sample < 0
```

**Update**

If you can use only select statement, then following decision can helps you.

```
with 
t as 
(
    select 1281 as sample from dual union all
    select -469 as sample from dual union all
    select -469 as sample from dual union all
    select -509 as sample from dual union all
    select -1359 as sample from dual union all
    select -1359 as sample from dual union all
    select -2759 as sample from dual union all
    select -2829 as sample from dual
)
select 
    case 
        when t.sample = (select max(t.sample) from t where t.sample < 0) then
            abs(t.sample)
        else
            t.sample
    end sample            
from 
    t
```

And the result of this query is:

```
sample
-------
1281
469
469
-509
-1359
-1359
-2759
-2829
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Brian Hello, thank you a lot. I edited my answer. I'll hope made it better.

Comment: Thanks Anton. I am not allowed to update the table and I need to make this happen in the Select statement using CASE. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: @Nick I updated my answer and added approach, that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below SQL which filters all negative number. Then order by descending order of the negative numbers and select only the first row.

```
update tab
set tab.val = ABS(tab.val)
WHERE
    tab.val < 0
ORDER BY tab.val DESC;
```